PJSIP crashes during release on iOS18
I checked the pool code and didn't find any issues.
Are there any changes in the iOS 18 system? This crash only report on iOS 18.
Here is the crash stack trace.

Crashed：Thread #1
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x006000a0005500af
0
Vostic
pool_i.h - 第 35 行
pj_pool_get_used_size + 35
1
Vostic
pool.c - 第 287 行
pj_pool_destroy_int + 287
2
Vostic
pool_caching.c - 第 235 行
cpool_release_pool + 235
3
Vostic
pool_i.h - 第 93 行
pj_pool_release + 93
4
Vostic
pool_i.h - 第 102 行
pj_pool_safe_release + 102
5
Vostic
sound_port.c - 第 1299 行
pjmedia_snd_port_destroy + 1299

Has anyone encountered this issue?
